# User Initials setting in Microsoft OneNote / Author Highlighting

Tags: windows-8, ios, microsoft-onenote

I have ended up with different initials on different devices in Microsoft OneNote. The result of them being different is that it thinks I am a different person making revisions and I end up with author highlighting all over the place.

In **OneNote 2010** on the PC the initials are set in the General Options Settings .. no problem here.

- How do I set the **user's initials** in the **Windows 8 Metro**
  version?
- And how do I set the **user's initials** in the **iOS**
  version?

**Or**, how can I turn off the author highlighting in the Windows 8 Metro App?

Answer (score 3):

The [OneNote App](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/onenote/f022389f-f3a6-417e-ad23-704fbdf57117), previously called OneNote MX, does not give you the ability to either change your name/initials or turn off author highlighting.  Microsoft did not see fit to include those features in the lightweight OneNote Metro application.

[There](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/how-to-hide-authors-in-onenote-app/6626c469-a284-4839-9406-6443424070b2) [have](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_mobile-onenote/authors-in-windows-store-onenote-app/531d9ee9-a3fd-4532-b720-494392d9ec09) [been](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-onenote/editing-notes-using-onenote-app-adds-my-initials/41a9e4c0-6531-4fec-b4f5-fada220bb0c8) other complaints and requests to Microsoft for this feature to be implemented.  No official response has been made from Microsoft yet, but the OneNote team does [listen](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-onenote/archive/2013/07/15/onenote-updates-windows-store-app-for-touch-and-office-365.aspx) to customer feedback in their [updates](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-onenote/archive/2013/11/25/a-big-onenote-update-for-windows-note-taking-devices.aspx).

So, you currently can't make the change in the OneNote Metro app.  The next thing to try is making the change in the full version of OneNote to match the name and initials you *can't* change in the Metro app.  I don't have a way to test that myself.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have added a question on the Microsoft forum. But it seems others are similarly struggling without solution. It would be good to find out where the Windows 8 App get the initial from. It must get it from somewhere!